# Handshake between ManyToMany relation created by Symfony's make:entity command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7

So, can you please clarify to me why the Symfony's command `make:entity` generates different `addProperty` methods to a `ManyToMany` relation?

I spent a few minutes trying to understand why and didn't get yet.

To Exemplify:

Assuming you have these two classes:

- Language
- Country

```sh
# Now running:
bin/console make:entity Country

# You'll enter in the interactive terminal, just type:
> languages
> ManyToMany
> Language
> yes
```

These steps will generate the following code in `Country` class:

```php
    ...
    public function addLanguage(Language $language): self
    {
        if (!$this->languages->contains($language)) {
            $this->languages[] = $language;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    ...
```

In the `Language` class you'll get this:

```php
    ...
    public function addCountry(Country $country): self
    {
        if (!$this->countries->contains($country)) {
            $this->countries[] = $country;
            $country->addLanguage($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    ...
```

I'm trying to understand why `Language` has the line `$country->addLanguage($this);` and `Country` doesn't have.

Comment: Think about what would happen if it did.  Or try it.

Comment: @Cerad if your guess it's because recursion, I don't think that is the case because of `!$this->countries->contains($country)`.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association

Comment: @Cerad the docs are a bit confusing according with the maker command. The docs says about `Article` as owner from `Tag`, so, `Article` is the `inverse side` and `Tag` is the `map side`. The docs says: `$tag->addArticle($this); // synchronously updating inverse side` but `Tag` isn't the `inverse side`. Look here to a better understanding: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/many-to-many . Therefore that, all this helps me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The article above answers my question:

> Remember, all of this owning versus inverse stuff is important because, when Doctrine saves an entity, it only looks at the owning side of the relationship to figure out what to save to the database. So, if we add tags to an article, Doctrine will save that correctly. But, if you added articles to a tag and save, Doctrine would do nothing. Well, in practice, if you use make:entity, that's not true. Why? Because the generated code synchronizes the owning side. If you call $tag->addArticle(), inside, that calls $article->addTag():

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

> Remember, all of this owning versus inverse stuff is important because, when Doctrine saves an entity, it only looks at the owning side of the relationship to figure out what to save to the database. So, if we add tags to an article, Doctrine will save that correctly. But, if you added articles to a tag and save, Doctrine would do nothing. Well, in practice, if you use make:entity, that's not true. Why? Because the generated code synchronizes the owning side. If you call `$tag->addArticle()`, inside, that calls `$article->addTag()`

Source: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/many-to-many